# A question about a fly and a spider

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, 3d

A spider is sitting exactly in the middle of one of the smallest walls in a living room, whilst a fly is resting by the side of the window of the opposite wall, 1.5 m above the ground and o.5 m from the adjacent wall. 
The room is 5m long, 4m wide and 2.5m high.
Work out the distance between spider and fly. 
(P.s: according to the answer sheet, the answer should be 5.23 m correct to 2dp, but i dont know how to get this answer)

The room and the location of the fly in the spider:

[image]

Comment: Weird thing (or not) that there is a window...and I guess the distance is meant going on walls/floor/ceiling, not in straight line, which seems to be reasonable easy, with straight triangles...?

Comment: I think it must be air distance, as I get this is 5.226 mts....

Comment: @DonAntonio It certainly is about the path along the room's inner surface – a spider can't fly! :)

Comment: This is an old problem, presented with different numeric parameters (room's dimensions). The most clear way to solve it is unfolding the cuboid room into a flat net and considering a straight way (line segment) between the two arthropods. Be aware, however, that you can draw the net in several different ways, which cause the 'straight' way to go through different edges, so you eventually have to choose the globally shortest path from several locally shortest.

Comment: @CiaPan Who said the spider can fly? Who even said anything about the spider wanting to hunt the fly?!

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KlDwT2l1K6k

Comment: @DonAntonio The book said that, in which I saw this puzzle for the first tme several decades ago.

Comment: @CiaPan - no, a book said that, in which you saw *a similar puzzle* for the first time several decades ago. This question simply asks for the distance from spider to fly, not the length of the shortest route the spider can take. Since the answer is known and matches the direct distance, we can be sure the classic puzzle was not intended.

Comment: The solution to this puzzle is to figure out from the information given what the cartesian coordinates of the two insects are, then use the distance formula to find the distance between them.

Answer (score 0):

[image: spider and fly]$A$ is the fly, $B$ the spider. Let $AKLC$ be a rectangle parallel to the floor, and draw $CD$ vertically and $BD$ horizontally. Since $LC=AK=.5m$, and $B$ is at the wall's center, then $$BD=2-.5=1.5m$$ and $$CD=1.5-1.25=.25m$$Therefore by Pythagoras$$CB=\sqrt {1.5^2+.25^2}=1.52m$$Then drawing $AB$, since $\triangle ACB$ is right, again by Pythagoras$$AB=\sqrt{5^2+1.52^2}=5.23m$$the distance between spider and fly.